# code meaning in java (i+"").getBytes()

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

java `byte []b = (i+"").getBytes()` where `i` is int

```
int i = 8;
byte []b = (i+"").getBytes();
```

I have seen this lines of code and cant understand what is the meaning of (i+"") thing.

Comment: `i+""` is just converting the integer to a String object.

Comment: so that this method can be used: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get `bytes` from the `String` representation of an `int` value. 
So you need a `String`.
You convert the `int` to a `String` by concatenating the `int` value with a empty `String` that produces a `String` and then you can invoke `String.getBytes()` to encode the `String` into a byte array.

> [**15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)
>
> if only one operand expression is of type String, then string
>   conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a
>   string at run time.

A more efficient and elegant way would be :

```
byte[] b = String.valueOf(i).getBytes();
```

Comment: "Getting the bytes from an int value" is a pretty ill-defined description of what's going on: you're not getting the 4-byte representation of the int, which is one interpretation of that. You're getting the ASCII value for each of the characters of the string representation of the int in base 10.

Comment: @Andy Turner, Right. It was not correctly formulated.  I Updated

Answer (score 3):

`i + ""` demonstrate that String concatenation with `int`.

If you expand that a bit. It's equals to

```
 String s = i+"";
 byte []b = s.getBytes();
```

However that's almost a hack to do so. Do not prefer concatenation unless you really need it.

Use overloadded method `valueOf(int i)` instead.

```
byte []b = String.valueOf(i).getBytes();
```

That gives you more readability and clean.

Answer (score 1):

`(i + "")` It's just a way to convert an int to a String, it's equivalent to :

```
String.valueOf(i)
```